# Is it OK to have ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0 and 2.0 dependencies in a single project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, recaptcha

I've added PaulMiami.AspNetCore.Mvc.Recaptcha package as a dependency to my ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0 project and I noticed lots of ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0 packages being installed during dotnet restore. It's because the package itself depends on the older version of the framework.

Everything seems to work fine, but are there any potential issues with having two different ASP.NET versions in a single project?

Comment: i believe it will cause some issues.. like you will need to add binding and such (and it may break on missing methods if any). what made you to chose that particular implementation instead the newer ones? perhaps you will need to reconsider it. really.

Comment: Well.. it's ok until it works I guess

Comment: It's the newest Recaptcha library for asp.net core mvc we could find. We didn't notice it depends on older asp.net core until today because everything seems to work without any issues. And we're wondering if it's OK to go live with it or we should integrate Recaptcha on our own.

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't *need* a Recaptcha library. It's *very* simple to implement, and if you really want an HtmlHelper extension, you can always write your own or better yet, create a taghelper. It's not worth having to add a bunch of old library dependencies to your project just to include a library that saves maybe 15 minutes of coding time.

Comment: It's not recommended or supported due to breaking changes across versions. If it happens to work, you got lucky.

Comment: Another [reCAPTCHA library](https://github.com/TimothyMeadows/reCAPTCHA.AspNetCore/) to consider.